# Google-Sheets - Break a loop based on cell value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently running a timer based script (once a week) that copies a couple of values from one range (source) to another (target).

The source range is the result of a query based on a import. Thus it goes through multiple calculation steps before displaying the proper result.
Usually this should be an easy task - just add a sleep timer to be sure and be done with it.
However, the script copies the data based on an unfinished calculation.

Here's how I approached the this:

I setup a cell that checks if the data was correctly copied (trigger cell)

Now, I could just run a timer on sunday every hour or so, checking if the trigger is true or false. But I was wondering if there is a way to do this with a loop.

I am fairly new to javascript so I'm not very confident with implementing possible solutions from the web.
It seems that loops can only be broken based on values within the loop. A do/while (while 'trigger' == false) loop for example just loops for 5 Minutes until it times out. I think a function call with the function calling itself should do the trick, but I couldn't figure out how to do this properly. My version just seems to run once and break - even when I change the triggervalue manually to force a loop.

```
    function looper(){

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("example");

    var trigger = sheet.getRange("a1").getValue();
    var source = sheet.getRange("b1:j1").getValues();
    var target = sheet.getRange("b2:j2");  

    Utilities.sleep(5000)
    if (trigger == false){
    target.setValues(source);
    looper;
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including the input and output you want?

Comment: BTW. You said _copies a couple of values from one range (source) to another (target)._ I just want to clarify something, if you are using "query based on a import" then you are **NOT** dealing with values per se, you are dealing the dynamic results of a formula. So you might want to consider a different command such as `copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)` where you can set an option [for what you want to paste](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/copy-paste-type) (and "transposed" is just an option, so you can turn it off).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, to call a function you need to use parentheses. So for the last line, try doing this: `looper();` instead.